# Npm Firebase tools install

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, node-modules, firebase-tools

I get such an error when I try to install Firebase tools with nodejs.

> C:\Users\yusuf\Desktop\restful>npm install -g firebase-tools
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "firebase-
>
> tools"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.11.3
>
> pm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! syscall read
>
> npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
>
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>
> npm ERR! network
>
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\yusuf\Desktop\restful\npm-debug.log

When I use this method I found in my research, the lines of code look like this.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0rQg.png)

Comment: This happens when your `network connection` is slow, or when ur network proxy setting is not allowing npm to download(if you are connected to vpn, disconnect and try). and try setting npm registry to https `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: I do not use vpn and when I change it to 'https' I get the above error. @kgangadhar

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are behind a proxy, i think this might help : `npm i -g firebase-tools -d`   .
Or you can use yarn `yarn add firebase-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

If you not use vpn
try:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```